# Need to rename the attached file name while sending mail in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

```
mail -s "$ENV : $REPORT_NAME Report for $BUSINESS_DATE " -a "$FILE_NAME" $EMAIL_ID
```

I have this command which is working fine in shell script, now my requirement is to rename the attached file.

suppose file name is `A.txt`
want to send `B.txt`

Please help me to get command.

Answer (score 0):

The `mail` doesn't have any option to attach the file with a different name. So you have left with renaming the file or copying it to a temporary file and send it:

```
cp "$FILE_NAME" /tmp/B.txt && FILE_NAME="/tmp/B.txt" && \
mail -s "$ENV : $REPORT_NAME Report for $BUSINESS_DATE " -a "$FILE_NAME" $EMAIL_ID && \
rm -f /tmp/tmp/B.txt
```

or you can move the original file, if you don't need to preserve its name:

```
mv "$FILE_NAME" /tmp/B.txt && FILE_NAME="/tmp/B.txt" && \
mail -s "$ENV : $REPORT_NAME Report for $BUSINESS_DATE " -a "$FILE_NAME" $EMAIL_ID
```

Comment: a link might be better with ln or ln -s